# Wrapping user_params in an array Android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to pass user sign up details to a rails user controller. While rails Rails creates the form tag using the @user object, I do not know how to do the same for android. I am using the following code to send a post request using Volley.

```
public class Register extends Activity {

Button btnLogin;
EditText inputUsername;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
EditText inputPasswordConfirmation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fld_username);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fld_email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fld_pwd);
    inputPasswordConfirmation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fld_pwd_confirm);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String username = String.valueOf(inputUsername.getText());
            final String email = String.valueOf(inputEmail.getText());
            final String password = String.valueOf(inputPassword.getText());
            final String passwordconfirmation = String.valueOf(inputPasswordConfirmation.getText());

            StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    "http://community.ngrok.com/users", new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    Log.d("Response", s);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    Log.d("Error",volleyError.toString());
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("name", username);
                    params.put("email",email);
                    params.put("password", password);
                    params.put("password_confirmation", passwordconfirmation);
                    return params;
                }
            };

            queue.add(postRequest);

            Intent home = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(home);

        }
    });
}
```

}

My rails new.html.erb for sign up code is

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

The error I get when I send the post request is

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: user):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:73:in `user_params'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

So my question is how do I wrap the user_params in an array using Volley in order to have the @user object

Answer (score 0):

Thats something you cannot do/ or not easy to do in Android. Serializeable class do exits in Android(java) but your implementation is a way different. You need to extract data from POST etc. from HTTP in order to use it.

Comment: what do you mean by extracting data from post?